# Help in proving that $\bigl (n^\alpha x^n (1-x) \bigr)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, sequence-of-function

I need some help in the following question:

> Let $\ 0<\alpha \in \mathbb R$. If $\bigl (f_n(x) \bigr)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ a  sequence of functions as $\forall n\in\mathbb N \ \ \ f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$:$$\forall n\in\mathbb N, \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb [0,1]: \ \ \ f_n(x)=n^\alpha x^n (1-x)$$

**Q:**  1. Prove that $\bigl (f_n(x) \bigr)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is pointwise convergent in $[0,1]$.

2. Prove that $\bigl (f_n(x) \bigr)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is uniformly convergent **iff** $\alpha<1$.

**My thought till now:** For the first part I tried to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha x^n (1-x)=0$ for a constant $x$ but the $n^\alpha$ is confusing me and I don't know how to continue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Just show the logarithm of
$$\ln(n^\alpha x^n)=\alpha\ln n+n\ln x \to -\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=1$ then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$. Suppose $0 \leq x <1$. Let $a=-\ln x$. Then $a>0$ and $n^{\alpha} x^{n}=n^{\alpha} e^{-na}$. Hence $n^{\alpha} x^{n}(1-x)\leq e^{-na} n^{k}$ where $k$ is an integer exceeding $\alpha$. A well known  consequence of L'Hopital's Rule is $e^{-na} n^{k} \to 0$ for any positive integer $k$ if $a>0$. Hence $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x$.

The maximum of $f_n$ is attained when $nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^{n}=0$ or $x =\frac n {n+1}$. The maximum value is $n^{\alpha} (\frac 1 {1+\frac 1  n})^{n} \frac 1 {n+1}$. Can you show that this tends to $0$ iff $\alpha <1$?

Answer (score 0):

1)Pointwise convergence:

$f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0;$

$x \in (0,1)$: Root test;

$\lim_{n}\sqrt [n]{f_n(x)}=$

$\lim_{n}(1-x)^{1/n}n^{a/n}x=x <1.$

Hence

$ \lim_{n}f_n(x)=0$ for $x \in [0,1].$

2)$0<a<1;$

$x \in (0,1):$ $x=\frac{1}{1+y}$, $y >0$;

$f_n(x)=n^a\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}(1-x) \lt$

$\left (\frac{n^a}{ny}\right )\frac{y}{1+y}<\frac{1}{n^{1-a}};$

$\sup_{x}f_n(x) \le \frac{1}{n^{1-a}};$

Thus $\lim_{n}\sup_{x} =0$, uniformly convergent for 0<a<1 in $[0,1]$.

Used: $(1+y)^n >1+yn$, $y>0$, binomial expansion.

Answer (score -1):

A different approach for the pointwise convergence: (the standard being using a continuous variable $t\to\infty$ instead of $n$ and using DLH)

To see that $f_n$ is pointwise convergent, fix $x\in[0,1]$. If $x=1$ or $x=0$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$, so $f_n(x)$ does indeed converge (to 0). If $x\in(0,1)$, we will show that $n^\alpha x^n\to0$, then obviously $f_n(x)\to 0$ as well.
Let $m$ denote the least integer with $\alpha\leq m$. Then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^m x^n\sim\sum_{n=m}^\infty n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)x^{n-m+1}$$

which is summable, as the $m$-th derivative of the geometric series. Thus $n^mx^n\to0$, so it is also $n^\alpha x^n\to0$.

Now to check uniform convergence, observe that the supremum of $f_n$ is attained at $x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$. Compute $f_n(x_n)$. It is $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-0|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|=f_n(x_n)$. You will see that $f_n(x_n)\to0$ if and only if $\alpha<1$.

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, the downvote is from @zkutch for no reason, just because I downvoted his own answer for handling an irrelevant case and for not answering completely to the question.

Answer (score -2):

We can write estimation:
$$|f_n(x)|=|n^\alpha x^n (1-x)| \leqslant n^\alpha$$
from which for $\alpha < 0$ you have as 1 so 2.

For case $0 < \alpha < 1$ It's easy find, that we have maximum in  $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and then  use criterion
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{}|n^\alpha x^n (1-x)|=\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\alpha} \left( \frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n+1}=0$$

Comment: but $\alpha>0$, so what's the point?

Comment: But we can say: $|f_n(x)|=|n^\alpha x^n (1-x)|=|n^\alpha x^n||1-x|=|(nx^{n \over \alpha})^{\alpha}||1-x|$.

Comment: For everybody: may be firstly is better to ask, think and discuss, then blindly down voting.

Comment: @The student. Your transformation is correct and which doubt you have?

Comment: The downvote is from me. It is not a blind downvote. You are handling a case that is irrelevant as $\alpha>0$ and the 2nd part is poorly written; Why does this hold for $0<\alpha<1$ only? the same is true for $\alpha\geq1$ as well, its just that the limit will not be 0. What about pointwise convergence? a person that is new to this will be confused by reading this answer.

Comment: @zkutch, I need to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (nx^{n \over \alpha})=0$$.

Comment: I can see that you have added things in your answer and I'm saying that I still don't like your answer, hence the downvote.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn. Do not talk with a person, do not hear his answers and do not be prepared for the fact that you also can make mistakes yourself or that others have their own opinion - this is blindness.We cannot give part of answer to encourage independent action? How many such answers have you? Convergence comes in case written and nobody know beforehand what issues confusing and what not. Farther questions and dialog clears and corrects answers and not blindly imagine yourself as the only point of truth. There is no text that everyone likes - dialogue and human relations is the way.

Comment: @zkutch Your answer is your opinion. My opinion is that your answer is not helpful, so the downvote is my opinion, there's no need for a whole speech.

Comment: @The student. Added one more transformation to show how maximum give uniform convergence. Your way will not give answer for uniform convergence as you lost |1−x| it's essential in maximum point to show that limit is 0. But for pointwise approach it's enough. For proof note that it is limit type $\frac{n}{a^n}$ where $a>1$, so it definitely goes to $0$